# Nested Query in Linq to entities with the same dbset

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following Linq query:

```
 var date = (from TA in _context.TAs
             where TA.Id == (from TB in _context.TAs
                             join TC in _context.TCs on TB.Id equals TC.Id
                             where TB.XXX == TA.XXX &&
                                   TB.YYY == yyy &&
                                   TB.Date < _Date
                             group TB by 1 into grouped
                             select grouped.Max(x => x.Id)).FirstOrDefault()
             select TA.Date).FirstOrDefault().AddMonth(1);
```

When I run the query, I get an exception:

```
ORA-00904: "Extent1"."XXX": invalid identifier
```

I know what this exception means, but all classes participating in this query are properly configured and mapped to the database since I use them in other LINQ to entities queries, not having any invalid identifier exceptions.

Can you, please, help me find the problem in this query?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Reduce your problem until you find a query as small as possible that failed. Then post it again!

Comment: Have a look at the actual SQL that is getting run. I don't know the best way to do this with Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
var date = (from TA in _context.TAs
            join TC in _context.TCs on TB.Id equals TC.Id
            where TA.YYY == yyy &&
                  TA.Date < _Date
            orderby TA.Id
            select TA.Date).Last();
```